# Existence of order-preserving bijective map

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Show that there does not exist any bijective map $\phi $ from

1. $\Bbb N \to \Bbb Z$
2. $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Q$
3. $\Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$

which satisfies $x_1\le x_2\implies \phi(x_1)\le \phi(x_2)$

Please give me some hints to start. I am totally clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1-3 consider that if such map exists, than $\mathbb Q$ (or $\mathbb Z$) has a minimum (because $\forall n \in \mathbb N $ you have $n>0$). For 2 consider for example $\phi (0) \in \mathbb Q$. If $\forall x>0$ in $\mathbb Z$ we have $   \phi(x)>\phi(0)$ than consider $\phi(1)$. It would be the least rational $q$ which is $>\phi(0)$. But so there would be no other rationals between $\phi(0)$ and $\phi(1)$, absurd.

Comment: Good work done;;

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If there's an order-preserving bijective map between two ordered sets $A$ and $B,$ then $A$ and $B$ look exactly the same except for the names of the elements (they're isomorphic). So if you find a property that is true of $A$ but false of $B,$ they can't be isomorphic. You just need to be sure that the property refers only to the ordering, not to anything else. Examples: "has a least element", "is dense".

That's probably enough for you to finish the problem.